# Owning stock in companies that operate on shabbat

Tags: money, shabbat, halacha

It is my understanding that one may only have ownership in a business that operates on shabbat if you co-own with a gentile and have an explicit arrangement that all profits derived on shabbat belong to him and not you, as one ought not benefit from work done on the day of rest. If this is true, then why is it permissible to own stock in large companies (denoting partial ownership), even when no such explicit arrangement is made?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Igros Moshe Even Ho'Ezer 1:7 writes that when you own stock in a company that you have no control over the day to day operations then it is permitted.

http://www.dailyhalacha.com/Display.asp?PageIndex=3&ClipID=1467

Comment: Would this apply to owning stock in a restaurant corporation that mixes meat and milk?  Wouldn't that be gaining a prohibited benefit from the issur?